# Liquibase gives different results from Ant and the command line

Tags: ant, liquibase

When I run Liquibase from the command line it populates the `FILENAME` column of `DATABASECHANGELOG` with the relative paths to the changelog files, as you'd hope. But when I run exactly the same changelog from exactly the same directory, using Ant, it populates the column with the absolute paths.

Among other things this means that the Ant and the command-line versions are not interoperable for me.

But I can't find anyone else having reported this problem, so I'm sure it's something I'm doing; something that I haven't set up correctly. I've seen some suggestions that the root directory of the changelog needs to be on the classpath, so I've included it in the Ant classpath, but it doesn't make any difference.

Here's my Ant build file:

```
<project name="Database Build" default="build" basedir="." xmlns:liquibase="antlib:liquibase.integration.ant">

<path id="liquibase.lib.path">
    <fileset dir="liquibase/lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="liquibase">
        <include name="liquibase.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="driver.classpath">
    <filelist files="${classpath}" />
</path>

<path id="main.classpath">
    <pathelement location="." />
    <path refid="driver.classpath" />
</path>

<taskdef 
    resource="liquibase/integration/ant/antlib.xml" 
    uri="antlib:liquibase.integration.ant">

    <classpath refid="liquibase.lib.path" />

</taskdef>

<liquibase:database 
    id="main-schema" 
    driver="${driver}" 
    url="${url}" 
    user="${username}" 
    password="${password}"
    defaultSchemaName="${defaultSchemaName}"
/>

<target 
    name="build"
    description="Builds the database based on values set in the properties file">

    <echo message="Building DB..." />
    <liquibase:updateDatabase 
        databaseref="main-schema" 
        changelogfile="${changeLogFile}"
        classpathref="main.classpath"
        logLevel="debug"
    >
        <!-- Here we're effectively passing the values set as Ant properties in as Liquibase parameters -->
        <liquibase:changeLogParameters>
            <liquibase:changeLogParameter name="main.schema" value="${defaultSchemaName}" />
            <liquibase:changeLogParameter name="tablespace.data" value="${tablespace.data}" />
            <liquibase:changeLogParameter name="tablespace.index" value="${tablespace.index}" />
            <liquibase:changeLogParameter name="tablespace.long" value="${tablespace.long}" />
        </liquibase:changeLogParameters>

    </liquibase:updateDatabase>

</target>

<target 
    name="createSchema"
    description="Create a schema on the database"
>
    <echo>${toString:main.classpath}</echo>

    <sql
        driver="${driver}"
        classpathref="main.classpath"
        url="${url}"
        userid="${username}"
        password="${password}"
        expandProperties="true"
    >
        <transaction>
            CREATE SCHEMA ${defaultSchemaName};
        </transaction>
    </sql>

</target>

<target 
    name="createOracleUsers"
    description="Create a user in Oracle"
>
    <sql
        rdbms="oracle"
        print="true"
        driver="${driver}"
        classpathref="main.classpath"
        url="${url}"
        userid="${username}"
        password="${password}"
        expandProperties="true"
    >
        <transaction>
            CREATE USER ${defaultSchemaName} IDENTIFIED BY ${defaultSchemaName} 
              default tablespace ${tablespace.data}
              temporary tablespace TEMP quota unlimited on ${tablespace.data}
              quota unlimited on ${tablespace.index};
            GRANT create session, alter session, create sequence, 
              create table, create view to ${defaultSchemaName};
        </transaction>

    </sql>
</target>

</project>
```

**Edited to add some changelog files.**

Here's the root changelog file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog 
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd 
                    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
                    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <include file="changes/sequences/sequences.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />   
    <include file="changes/baseobjects/db-511.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
    <include file="changes/data/data-511.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />

</databaseChangeLog>
```

The first of the included ones starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog 
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.3.xsd 
                    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext 
                    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <changeSet dbms="oracle,db2,db2i" author="mccallim (generated)" id="1419011907193-1">
        <createSequence schemaName="${main.schema}" cacheSize="100" cycle="false" incrementBy="1" minValue="1" sequenceName="SEQ_ALLOWEDCURRENCIES" startValue="1"/>
    </changeSet>
...
</databaseChangeLog>
```

It has lots of other sequences. The next one does the tables, indexes and views, and is pretty much as you'd expect.

Comment: Can you include an example of your changelog? Is the problem with included changelogs or the root changelog itself?

Comment: Thanks @Nathan. I'll add the changelog when I'm back at work. But in short, it's everything. The main changelog is just a series of includes to pull in the detailed ones. But the key thing is that from the command line I get the relative path, while from Ant they're absolute. I want to use Ant because I'm using its `<sql>` element to create the actual schema (or user, if it's Oracle), before Liquibase creates the tables and everything else.

Comment: @NathanVoxland, I've added some of the changelog files. I can add more detail if you like, or show the file structure, or whatever. Just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug. I created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2290 to track the fix for 3.3.3

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Good to know it's not just me. Though surprising that no-one else seems to have noticed it.